# Vue Reactivity when using Typescript classes

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have a Vue 2.6.10 app running Typescript 3.6.3.

I have a Typescript class declared that performs some standard functions for the application.  I have a plugin that assigns the instance of that class to Vue's prototype.

No public member of that instantiated class is reactive regardless of its type.

I distilled the example down https://codepen.io/ColdToast/pen/KKwwjwY

**Class**

```js
class Module {
    public _person = null;

    constructor() {}

    get person() {
        return this._person;
    }

    set person(val) {
        this._person = val;
    }

    fetchData() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => resolve('Person data'), 1000);
        });
    }
}
```

**Plugin and App**

```js
const MyPlugin = {
    install(Vue) {
        Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
            $module: { value: new Module() }
        });
    }
};

const App = {
    name: 'App',

    template: `<p>Hello {{ name }}</p>`,

    computed: {
        // Expect to resolve to 'Person data'
        name() {
            return this.$module.person;
        }
    },

    async created() {
        // I expect `data` to be 'Person data'
        const data = await this.$module.fetchData();

        // Properly logs 'Person data'
        console.log(data);

        this.$module.person = data;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass the instance of the class to the `data` of `Vue` then everything works as expected. Its not ideal but the following works:

```
const App = {
    name: 'App',

    template: `<p>Hello {{ name }}</p>`,

    computed: {
        // Expect to resolve to 'Person data'
        name() {
            return this.$module.person;
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            module: this.$module
        };
    },

    async created() {
        const data = await this.$module.fetchData();

        this.$module.person = data;
    }
};
```